# IndexOutOfRangeException Thrown for a string .split c#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, string

I have an application using the MySQL .Net connection but for some reason i'm having a problem parsing the results to return them,

```
public NameValueCollection[] query(string query)
{
    connect();
    NameValueCollection[] resultSet;

    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader Reader;

    command.CommandText = query;
    connection.Open();
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    string theserows = "";
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++){
            theserows += Reader.GetName(i)+"="+Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",";
            Count = i;
        }
        theserows += "\n";
    }
    connection.Close();
    string[] results = theserows.Split(new char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int countResultRows = 0;
    resultSet = new NameValueCollection[Count];
    foreach (string s in results)
    {
        resultSet[countResultRows] = new NameValueCollection();
        string[] result = s.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string col in results)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(col))
                continue;

            string[] kv = col.Split('=');
            resultSet[countResultRows].Add(kv[0], kv[1]);
        }
        countResultRows++;
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

In this `theserows = "site_id=1,\n"` but i have an exception thown on the `string[] result = s.Split(',');` with the exception `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Could any one give any insight into why this error would be occurring?

On another note the reason i'm reading it all then building the NameValueCollection is I want to add a logging system that logs the full query and it's results

EDIT::

"count"(lowercase) changed to countResultRows

CallStack

```
HTML5Streamer.exe!HTML5Streamer.Classes.MySQL.query(string query) Line 53   C#
HTML5Streamer.exe!HTML5Streamer.Classes.Query.getSiteId(string domain) Line 17 + 0x10 bytes C#
HTML5Streamer.exe!HTML5Streamer.Classes.Query.checkUserPass(string username, string password, string domain) Line 31 + 0xb bytes    C#
HTML5Streamer.exe!HTML5Streamer.Classes.Service.ProccessAdminRequest(System.Net.HttpListenerContext context) Line 239 + 0xd9 bytes  C#
HTML5Streamer.exe!HTML5Streamer.Classes.Service.ProcessRequest(System.Net.HttpListenerContext context) Line 176 + 0xb bytes C#
HTML5Streamer.exe!HTML5Streamer.Classes.Service.ListenerCallback(System.IAsyncResult result) Line 150 + 0xb bytes   C#
```

[image: Full Exception Detiails]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EST4w.png
Line 52 is `resultSet[countResultRows] = new NameValueCollection();`
 function starts at line 26 ends at 65

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException must be thrown on `resultSet[count] = new NameValueCollection();`

Comment: Try to use `string[] results = theserows.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); ` and `string[] result = s.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and tell us what happens...

Comment: Is that your real code?  Having variables named 'count' and 'Count' is a really bad idea.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code snippet - shouldn't the second foreach loop go through result array, not the results?

Comment: The first mistake here was putting delimited values inside a database cell. That's a huge no-no.

Comment: I Don't i do as the .Net Connection returns them i parse them into a CSV layout other that its using Key=Value, then i try to build the Name, i will post my full code

Comment: @PLB http://postimage.org/image/hanz4t8j1/ to the first comment

Comment: Did you check if s is not empty before spliting? oR use the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries option as @Marco said?

Comment: using the RemoveEmptyEntries still not working sorry some body answered with that and i forgot to update my questions code

Comment: Could you attach the exception message details? Stack trace...Eventually do a debug and check if the editor is not actually returning the wrong line.

Comment: Running your code, I have an OutOfRange Exception but on the resultSet[countResultRows].Add(kv[0], kv[1]); line, as I expected.

Comment: i would expect it there aswell not sure why it's not :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11196/discussion-between-lcfseth-and-martin-barker)

Comment: To Everyone thanks for your help between your help i have got rid of the error and thanks to @lcfseth for all the help in Chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use same variable names for 2 different values (count, Count), even if it is syntactically correct, this can be confusing.

Second, you should check if kv length is > 1 before accessing the array

```
resultSet[count].Add(kv[0], kv[1]);
```

If I follow the logic of you program, given the string "site_id=1,\n", after the split, 
result = {"site_id=1","\n"}, for the second string kv = {"\n"} and therefor kv[1] will return an OutOfRangeException.

Here's how I would've written your code

```
string[] results = theserows.Split(new char[]{'\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
resultSet = new NameValueCollection[Count];
for(int i = 0; i < results.Length && i < Count; i++)
{
    string s = results[i];
    resultSet[i] = new NameValueCollection();
    string[] result = s.Split(new char[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string col in result) // As pointed by other users, this should be result insead of results, again bad var name choice
    {
        string[] kv = col.Split('=');
        if(kv.Length >= 2)
        resultSet[i].Add(kv[0], kv[1]);
    }
 }
```

Avoiding any possible OutOfRangeExceptions

Comment: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group' -- Compiler Error (VS highlighted by i clicked Debug just to test)

Comment: Thanks for going the Extra Mile +1

Answer (score 1):

Just before the second loop you try to split string "site_id=1," with a comma being a separator - the result will be an array of two strings with the second one being empty. Just change your inner foreach loop to the following:

```
foreach (string col in result)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(col))
        continue;

    string[] kv = col.Split('=');
    resultSet[count].Add(kv[0], kv[1]);
}
```

Comment: You are pointing the right error, but your answer would fail to a "site_id=1,anystringwithoutequal" string value.

Comment: True, there is quite a lot of error checking logic missing in this code snippet

Comment: There is no error checking yet as i would like it to work before i start catching errors that are not normall

P.S this fix does not work same error

Comment: Thanks for this fix although it did not stop the problem it has helped +1

Answer (score 1):

you have problem of trailing commas and spaces. Plus you are iterating through `results` when you should be iterating through `result`. Try this.

```
string[] results = theserows.Trim().Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); ;
int count = 0;
resultSet = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection[results.Length];
foreach (string s in results)
{
    resultSet[count] = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    string[] result = s.Trim().Split(new string[] { ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string col in result)
    {
        string[] kv = col.Split('=');
        resultSet[count].Add(kv[0], kv[1]);
    }
    count++;
}
```